# Optimize returned value from custom hook to prevent rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

Imagine I have some custom hook where I extract some value from context ( some kind of my own store )

```
// example of state structure

function GlobalComponent(){
 const initialState = {
   reports: {depositReport: []},
   users: [],
 }

 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

 return <StoreContext.Provider value={{state}}></State.Provider>
}
```

```
const useSelector = (callback: (state: State) => State) => {
  const { state } = useContext(StoreContext);

  return callback(state);
};
```

and here is example of how I use this hook

```
function Component() {
 const { depositReport } = useSelector(state => state.reports);
}
```

when I extract `depositReport` value from state by example above in `Component` , it will rerender each time any property changes in `state` object. But how can I optimize `useSelector` hook , to rerender component when it used only when particular value `state => state.reports` will be changed .

Check example on codesandbox, and you will see that when I change `users` property , it rerenders place where I only extract `reports.depositReport` but I want optimiza `useSelector` hook in way , it will only rerender when I extract value on which change I want to react

[image: Edit late-monad-c6pt8l]

Comment: How did you change the state? Create a running https://codesandbox.io/ demo to explain your question

Comment: You can implement throttling + refs to reduce costly re-renders in the UI which will result in a great performance improvement, although I cannot see if that is an option here as I don't have all the necessary information. I support @LinDu's suggestion to upload your code to a sandbox and give us something concrete to work with.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-monad-c6pt8l?file=/src/App.js - here you can find example , you will see in this example , that when I change users , it also rerender component where I extract depositReport , but I want place where I extract deposit report only rerender in case deposit report change . But don't show examples with memo wrapper on component, I want optimiza useSelector hook @LinDu

Comment: Try this code. I implemented useMemo in your useSelector and useCallback in the User component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-joliot-w2wp8l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Dimitar but it hasn't changed anything , reports  component rerenders anytime I click button on users component

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich That is expected behavior - you are altering the state to which that component subscribes and a re-render is inevitable. Do you only want to update the UI based on user-change (i.e. change from state 1, 2, 3 to 1, 2 4 should only change for 3->4 instead of re-rendering 1, 2, 3 -> 1, 2, 4? This requires unitizing your components and subscribing to the state on an individual level for each user which will cause more troubles when scaling vertically for more users).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible this way. It uses context which value changes on each render. If that value changes, every children component that use `useContext(StoreContext)` rerenders. There is no way to prevent that.

What you can do is to use a third party library like `use-context-selector` or create your own store. It is not that simple as just calling useContext

Comment: This is treating the symptoms. The proper way to solve this is by implementing a throttle system within the context and then implementing ref-based UI wherever you subscribe to the state. That way, you will be able to render the UI independently of the context while keeping your context up to date with minimum delay which is controlled by the throttling mechanism. This, however is very case-specific. and is usually done only when working with CPU-intensive re-renders and clalculations that take place on the front-end.

Comment: @Oktay , thanks for your answer , but I want to make it without third-party

Comment: It is not possible the way you think. It is tricky to do that, there is no direct solution to this. You have to implement your own store, where each component can subscribe and send their setState, so when someone updates the store it can loop over those subscribers and based on the selector to call their setState.  It is how store libraries work. I can't explain the whole process here, you have to know how things work, but you can read how those libraries work and how they manage those store selectors. You have to ensure that the value you pass into the provider does not change over renders

Answer (score 0):

So based on the provided sandbox, I was able to find two key places where you can reduce unnecessary re-renders:

- The `useSelector` function
- The `Users` component where you are subscribing to the state

Here are the implemented changes:

```
const useSelector = (callback) => {
  const { state } = useContext(StoreContext);
  const selectedState = callback(state);

  return useMemo(() => selectedState, [JSON.stringify(selectedState)]);
};
```

Here, the use of `useMemo` will recompute the selected part of the state if either the callback function or the state object changes. Furthermore, having the `jsonified` version of your selectedState will ensure that if there is no change in your state, then you will not trigger a re-render. This will not work when you change state from `[1, 2, 3] to [3, 2, 1]` which is similar array (not identical).

This, however, requires that you wrap the `callback` function in a `useCallback` hook whenever you call it from your components, hence the updated `Users` component:

```
const Users = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectUsers = useCallback((state) => state.users, []);
  const users = useSelector(selectUsers);

  console.log(users, "users");
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({
            type: UsersE.SET_USERS,
            payload: {
              data: ["first", "second"]
            }
          });
        }}
      >
        Change users
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: but check logs , it rerender Reports component , even with your optimization

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich Reports is rendered so it must log `console.log(depositReport, "deposit-report");`. If you are refering to the double-log, that is caused by `StrictMode` in your `App.js` - it is mentioned in the official react docs. It will not happen in production. The memo and callback will reduce renders based on state-changes that do not effect the UI that renders specifically based on users. A change in users however small will still cause a re-render, there is no work-around except implementing the same code on a lower level in the state tree and subscribing from lower level components.

Comment: no , I understand why it is rerendered twice , but when you will remove StrictMode wrapper , you will see , that it is still called console.log(depositReport, "deposit-report"); when you click on button , this is what i don't like , it isn't right , what when I have store ( there can be a lot of different properites ), when some not related property change , it rerenders all my components , where I use StoreContext , but I want to optimize it

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich OK, so one solution is to implement a control mechanism. See my updated code and try to see if it works.

Comment: this is why I've written that I want to only optimize useSelector hook , to make it reusable , offcouse I also can create solutions , for example put const { depositReport } = useSelector(state => state.reports); on level above Reports , and pass in reports depositReport property as props , and then use memo with areEqual function , where i will compere prev and next depositReport property and rerender Reports only when prev and next aren't equal , but I don't like to make it in every place, I just want reusable hook for extraction and property I want  from state and it will be m-ized